# How to get index of a json and use it in pojo class

Tags: java, json, retrofit, pojo

I have a JSON like this. 
I am using retrofit to get it.
the first index is the time that comes from a website and updates every 4 hours.

this is my json :

> ```
>   {
>         "2018-01-01-20-00": {
>             "donations": 4070,
>             "memberCount": 50,
>             "members": [
>                 {
>                     "clanRank": 1,
>                     "crowns": 0,
>                     "donations": 58,
>                     "name": "Min",
>                     "tag": "L88P2282",
>                     "trophies": 4610
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "clanRank": 2,
>                     "crowns": 0,
>                     "donations": 76,
>                     "name": "matiz",
>                     "tag": "G0JVYY0",
>                     "trophies": 4443
>                 },
>             ]
>         },
>         "2018-01-02-00-00": {
>         },
>     }
> ```

as you can see the time index is Variable(changeable).

how can I make POJO class for this JSON?

Comment: learn to google, its an amazing skill, you are looking for something like this
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: unfortunately this site can not help me . because this site just make pojo . but i dont want to know how to create pojo  i know it . i just want to know how to get index and use it.@Ezio

Comment: You need to create a List of POJOs, so you can get the item with `List.get(index);` If this time variables will be dynamic I recommend use a JSON array instead of JSON objects

Comment: thanks . you mean its better to change the json before sending it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you parse this JSON as a `Map<String,SomeExampleClass>` where `SomeExampleClass` is a POJO that you create to represent the objects associated with each of the dates.

For example I used the inner portion of your JSON on [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) (I selected gson as the annotation style) and generated POJO classes.

Here is the portion of the JSON:

```
{
    "donations": 4070,
    "memberCount": 50,
    "members": [
        {
            "clanRank": 1,
            "crowns": 0,
            "donations": 58,
            "name": "Min",
            "tag": "L88P2282",
            "trophies": 4610
        },
        {
            "clanRank": 2,
            "crowns": 0,
            "donations": 76,
            "name": "matiz",
            "tag": "G0JVYY0",
            "trophies": 4443
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are the generated classes, with a `toString` method I added via Eclipse:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

    @SerializedName("donations")
    @Expose
    private Integer donations;
    @SerializedName("memberCount")
    @Expose
    private Integer memberCount;
    @SerializedName("members")
    @Expose
    private List<Member> members = null;

    public Integer getDonations() {
        return donations;
    }

    public void setDonations(Integer donations) {
        this.donations = donations;
    }

    public Integer getMemberCount() {
        return memberCount;
    }

    public void setMemberCount(Integer memberCount) {
        this.memberCount = memberCount;
    }

    public List<Member> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(List<Member> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example [donations=" + donations + ", memberCount=" + memberCount + ", members=" + members + "]";
    }

}
```

This is the class representing each member:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Member {

    @SerializedName("clanRank")
    @Expose
    private Integer clanRank;
    @SerializedName("crowns")
    @Expose
    private Integer crowns;
    @SerializedName("donations")
    @Expose
    private Integer donations;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("tag")
    @Expose
    private String tag;
    @SerializedName("trophies")
    @Expose
    private Integer trophies;

    public Integer getClanRank() {
        return clanRank;
    }

    public void setClanRank(Integer clanRank) {
        this.clanRank = clanRank;
    }

    public Integer getCrowns() {
        return crowns;
    }

    public void setCrowns(Integer crowns) {
        this.crowns = crowns;
    }

    public Integer getDonations() {
        return donations;
    }

    public void setDonations(Integer donations) {
        this.donations = donations;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public Integer getTrophies() {
        return trophies;
    }

    public void setTrophies(Integer trophies) {
        this.trophies = trophies;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member [clanRank=" + clanRank + ", crowns=" + crowns + ", donations=" + donations + ", name=" + name
                + ", tag=" + tag + ", trophies=" + trophies + "]";
    }

}
```

Now here is some example code to parse the JSON as a `Map`:

```
package gson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.Example;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        byte[] jsonBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("./src/main/java/gson/jsonData.json"));
        String json = new String(jsonBytes);

        Map<String,Example> result = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Example>>(){}.getType());

        System.out.println("RESULTS: "+result);
    }

}
```

To test this I used the following JSON input:

```
{
        "2018-01-01-20-00": {
            "donations": 4070,
            "memberCount": 50,
            "members": [
                {
                    "clanRank": 1,
                    "crowns": 0,
                    "donations": 58,
                    "name": "Min",
                    "tag": "L88P2282",
                    "trophies": 4610
                },
                {
                    "clanRank": 2,
                    "crowns": 0,
                    "donations": 76,
                    "name": "matiz",
                    "tag": "G0JVYY0",
                    "trophies": 4443
                }
            ]
        },
        "2018-01-02-00-00": {
        }
    }
```

and the result was the following output:

> RESULTS: {2018-01-01-20-00=Example [donations=4070, memberCount=50,
>   members=[Member [clanRank=1, crowns=0, donations=58, name=Min,
>   tag=L88P2282, trophies=4610], Member [clanRank=2, crowns=0,
>   donations=76, name=matiz, tag=G0JVYY0, trophies=4443]]],
>   2018-01-02-00-00=Example [donations=null, memberCount=null,
>   members=null]}

You can then [iterate over the entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46898/3284624) in the `Map` as needed.

Comment: thanks . you explained me basics and i've done what is in my mind by your solution . perfect !!!

Comment: if you know any training video about maps that could be useful for me i would be happy to know . its not matter if that come from youtube or anywhere . i just want to be professional in working with map !!!

Comment: `Map` is part of the [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and that is where you should probably begin learning about them.